# Reference to my subfloats always reference to Fig 1a, 1b or 1c

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I have a document where **multiple** figures with subfloats are included, like this one:

```
\documentclass[pdftex, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
test
\ref{fig:2ref1}
\ref{fig:1ref1}
\section{test}
\begin{figure}[h]
\subfloat[][caption1]{
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{pictures/1.pdf}
\label{fig:1ref1}
}
\subfloat[][caption]{
\includegraphics{pictures/2.pdf}
\label{fig:1ref2}
}
\end{figure}
\section{test2}
\begin{figure}[h]
\subfloat[][caption]{
\includegraphics[]{pictures/1.pdf}
\label{fig:2ref1}
}
\subfloat[][captio]{
\includegraphics{pictures/2.pdf}
\label{fig:2ref2}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The problem now is that both     `\ref{fig:2ref1}` and    `\ref{fig:1ref1}` return `1a` as picture reference, even if they are different pictures and should be `1a` and `2a`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The code should be compilable, start with `\documentclass{...}` and end  with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, hopefully the example should be an minimal example now.

Comment: scrartcl doesn't fix my problem if i do so both pictures are named 1a? Instead of 1a and 2a?

Comment: You do not have a `\caption{<caption text>}` in the first figure, so the `figure` counter is not incremented, and in the second `figure` you're still at figure 1.

Comment: but if i have 5 pictures in one section they can't be all figure one ? how could i distinct then?

Comment: If you don't want to have a "real" caption within your figures you could use `\phantomcaption` instead. Beside other stuff, this will increment the `figure` counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in comment, the problem is that the `figure` counter is not incremented, because you do not have a `\caption` in the `figure` environments. If you add a caption inside each figure, outside the subfloats, you get the desired outcome.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\begin{document}

\ref{fig:1ref1}
\ref{fig:1ref2}

\ref{fig:2ref1}
\ref{fig:2ref2}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat[][caption1]{
FIGURE 1A
\label{fig:1ref1}
}
\subfloat[][caption]{
FIGURE 1B
\label{fig:1ref2}
}
\caption{First figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat[][caption]{
FIGURE 2A
\label{fig:2ref1}
}
\subfloat[][captio]{
FIGURE 2B
\label{fig:2ref2}
}
\caption{Second figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `subfig` package documentation states, that the command `\p@subfigure` is prepended to the reference texts and that it defaults to `\thefigure`. As you don't caption your figures, this is always 1. In the MWE you might want to prepend `\thesection` instead. So this should help:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thesection}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I dont even think subfigure package is the same as the subfig package, which replaced the first a while ago? I'm lost ....

Comment: Ah sorry, that was my mistake. I meant the subfig package, that OP used. Changed it.